# Out Of Memory with images in Android 5

Tags: java, android, image-processing, out-of-memory

My app loading lot of images from network and decode it via `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray`. But when the application is decoded many images throws error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. So before i set flag `inPurgeable = true` in `BitmapFactory.Options` and this error will never not bother me.

In Android 5 field `BitmapFactory.Options.inPurgeable` is deprecated and `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` is thrown again after decoding a large amount of images.

What I should use in Android 5 to avoid this error?

**EDIT:**

My code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPurgeable = true;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer.toByteArray(), 0, buffer.length(), options);
```

It all. This works fine on Android 4 or less.

Stacktrace on Android 5:

```
    11-24 22:40:06.738: E/AndroidRuntime(19216): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
    11-24 22:40:06.738: E/AndroidRuntime(19216): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    11-24 22:40:06.738: E/AndroidRuntime(19216):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    11-24 22:40:06.738: E/AndroidRuntime(19216):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    11-24 22:40:06.738: E/AndroidRuntime(19216):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    11-24 22:40:06.738: E/AndroidRuntime(19216):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    11-24 22:40:06.738: E/AndroidRuntime(19216):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    11-24 22:40:06.738: E/AndroidRuntime(19216):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    11-24 22:40:06.738: E/AndroidRuntime(19216):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    11-24 22:40:06.738: E/AndroidRuntime(19216):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    11-24 22:40:06.738: E/AndroidRuntime(19216): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1638412 byte allocation with 326188 free bytes and 318KB until OOM
    11-24 22:40:06.738: E/AndroidRuntime(19216):    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    11-24 22:40:06.738: E/AndroidRuntime(19216):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
    11-24 22:40:06.738: E/AndroidRuntime(19216):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:522)
...
```

Comment: Maybe add in some code.

Comment: @TimRijckaert what to add?

Comment: Are these images locally stored? Do you fetch them online?
Can you show the stacktrace. Some code may also help for the community to see what you are doing now it's just vague.

Comment: Check this out see if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941509/android-fragment-with-three-listviews-crashes-with-out-of-memory-error/26941825#26941825

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the problem using this guide: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: The day will come when Google decided to kill off the link. So my future self will stumble on your answer and wondering, what was your answer actually?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a five-part tutorial by Google, which is hard to distill into a short answer. Alas, that's what I was looking for but I will need to read the tutorial now.